# Getting null value in h2 database when using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying to insert data into the h2 database taking input from user.But primary key is getting inserted but the other is stored as null.

Here is my application.properties

```
spring.sql.init.platform==h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:preethi
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization: true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Here is Controller class AlienController.java

```
package com.preethi.springbootjpa.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.preethi.springbootjpa.model.Alien;
import com.preethi.springbootjpa.repo.AlienRepo;

@Controller
public class AlienController {
    @Autowired
    AlienRepo repo;
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home()
    {
        return "home.jsp";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/addAlien")
   public String addAlien( Alien alien)
   {
        repo.save(alien);
       return "home.jsp";
   }
}
```

Here is Alien.java

```
package com.preethi.springbootjpa.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
@Entity
public class Alien {
    @Id
    private int aid;
    
    private String aname;
    public Alien()
    {
        
    }
    public Alien(int aid, String aname) {
        super();
        this.aid = aid;
        this.aname = aname;
    }
    public int getAid() {
        return aid;
    }
    public void setAid(int aid) {
        this.aid = aid;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return aname;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.aname = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alien [aid=" + aid + ", name=" + aname + "]";
    }

}
```

Here is AlienRepo.java

```
package com.preethi.springbootjpa.repo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.preethi.springbootjpa.model.Alien;

public interface AlienRepo extends CrudRepository<Alien,Integer>{

    
    
}
```

Here is data.sql;

```
insert into alien values(101,'Preethi');
```

when I try to insert data from data.sql,it is getting inserted but when I try to insert data taking input from user, data is stored as null(except primary key).

Here is the table :

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6tvJ.png)

Comment: Best to post the sql ddl create statement rather than an image.

Comment: yes, there is no issue in creating a table.The issue is that except the primary key, remaining are stored as null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it, there is no problem with the code...It's just all the configuraton things that messed up.
Just did everything from scratch and took care of build path and configurations.
Solved..

Comment: Can you tell me exactly what you change in the configuration?

Comment: what do you change in the configuration?

Comment: I was using STS -Spring Tool Suite and I noticed that profile isn't enabled. That's the only problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue when i forgot to add the gettters and setters for an entity class.

Comment: thank you ... exactly what happend to me . 
make just getters and forget setters